# symfony2 form fields into single column

Tags: php, forms, symfony, orm, entity

how to resolve this problem: javascript send two values: 1st field is date type and 2nd field is only time type, example:

Entity:

```
class Something
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateAndTime", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateAndTime;
```

Requested data is just simple string: 'fieldDate': '2014-05-23' and 'fieldTime': '17:00:00'
How to build form to trigger setter for dateAndTime (Maybe there is more sophisticated solution then create two separated fields in the entity)?

Comment: I would unmap those two fields and set the dateAndTime manually in your model before persisting it. You could also try a [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html).

Comment: Without knowing your reasoning it's difficult to give an answer. If you just want to separate the entities I believe you can use the options (for a datetime field) `'date_widget' => 'single_text', 'time_widget' => 'single_text'`. This way it will still map to your single field.

Comment: Reason is simple, my javascript framework send data like that: '2014-05-05T23:32:33' and i have to store it into database